# AngularFire2 - check if object exists before update

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Let's say I'm collecting a username, and I want to check if this username already exists in my Firebase database. AngularFire2 `update` or `set` methods don't actually check if the object exists, but replaces it if so. Is there a way to check that and say return a observable error?

Currently my solution is to retrieve the object and if there are results, I know it exists. I'm looking for a more straightforward way to check that.

I need to do that as a database object, not an actual user in Authentication.

```
let userExists = false;

this.af.database.object('/users/' + newUser.name).subscribe( user => {
    if (user) {
      userExists = true;
      console.log('This username is taken. Try another one');
    }
    else {
      this._af.database.object('/users/' + newUser.name).update({
         email: 'johndoe@example.com',
         password: '!@#$1234'
     })
   }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Firebase Transaction

Firebase provides a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) method for this situation.

> `transaction()` is used to modify the existing value to a new value, ensuring there are no conflicts with other clients writing to the same location at the same time.

If if the value is not present, then you just return the value you previously sent via `update`.

```
this.af.database.object('/users/' + newUser.name).$ref.transaction(currentValue => {
  if (currentValue === null) {
    return {email: 'johndoe@example.com', password: '!@#$1234'};
  } else {
    console.log('This username is taken. Try another one');
    return Promise.reject(Error('username is taken'))
  }
})
.then( result => {
   // Good to go, user does not exist
   if (result.committed) {
      // TODO: Take additional action
   }
})
.catch( error => {
   // handle error
});
```

It's important to note that this is a method from the Firebase API (not Angularfire2), but you can still access those methods by calling `$ref`.

Comment: Thanks! @adriancarriger . It works!!. I added some additional details in the implementation.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!

Comment: The above code works for adding new object. But try to use it also for remove by `currentValue.remove()` but getting error currentValue.remove is not a function. How can I do remove?

Comment: To remove an object using `transaction` just set the new value to null. If you show your exact code in a new question it might be easier to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I had a similar issue using AngaularFire4 so posting this to help anyone else:

```
this.db.object(`/users/${uid}`).first().subscribe(x => {
    if (x.$exists()){
          console.log(`FOUND`,x);
    }else {
          console.log(`NOT FOUND`);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.realtimedbService.getOneItem(key,  'colection').valueChanges()
              .subscribe(
                  result => {
                      if (result === null) {
                          console.log('NOT EXIST');

                                     }
                      if (result !== null) {
                        console.log('EXIST');
                        /// PUT YOUR UPPDATE METHODE HERE

                      }
                  },
                  error => {
                      console.log(" EE : ");
                      console.log(error);
                  }
              );
```

Comment: While code only answers might answer the question, it is very beneficial for the community if you provide context to what your code does and why it does this.